# I cannot see a created dataset in cloudconnect

Tags: dataset, gd, gooddata

I have created a dataset user in logical data model and publish it. Then, I wanted to connect the dataset in GD Writer, but in select box the dataset is not supported to be select. Does someone know where is the problem?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably with setting the right ${GDC_PROJECT_ID} parameter in workspace.prm file.